# Removing unwanted comma and updating a column

Tags: r, if-statement, substring, gsub

I have a dataset like this

```
      Id         Comments
      1          ,,,,A,,,,,B,,,,,,C
      2          ,,,,,,A,,,,,,,C,,,
      3          
      4          ,,,,,,,,,,Z,,,,,,,,
```

What I am trying to produce is an output like this

```
      Id    Feedback     Comments
      1     Yes          A,B,C
      2     Yes          A,C
      3     NA     
      4     Yes          Z
```

Need help here.

-----------------------Subset of actual data-------------------------

```
     t9 = structure(list(ID = c(242938L, 309790L, 339402L), Description = c("", 
                                                              " , , , , , , , , , , , A, , , , , , , , , , , B, , , , , , C, , , , D, , , , , , , , , , E, , , , , , , , , , , F", 
                                                              " , , A, , , D, , , , , , , , , S, , , , , , , D")), .Names = c("ID", "Comments"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the unwanted "," with `gsub`, create a new column ("Feedback") based on whether the elements in "Comments" are empty strings or not (`nzchar`).

```
df1$Comments <- gsub(',+', ',', gsub('^,+|,+$', '', df1$Comments))
df1$Feedback <- ifelse(nzchar(df1$Comments), 'Yes', NA)
df1
#  Id Comments Feedback
#1  1    A,B,C      Yes
#2  2      A,C      Yes
#3  3              <NA>
#4  4        Z      Yes
```

Or you could change the "Comments" column

```
library(stringr)
df1$Comments <- sapply(str_extract_all(df1$Comments, '[A-Za-z]+'), toString)
```

#### Update

Using `t9` data, remove the "spaces" and use the code above

```
t9$Comments <- gsub(' ', '', t9$Comments)
(t9$Comments <- gsub(',+', ',', gsub('^,+|,+$', '', t9$Comments)))
 #[1] ""            "A,B,C,D,E,F" "A,D,S,D"
```

#### data

```
df1 <-   structure(list(Id = 1:4, Comments = c(",,,,A,,,,,B,,,,,,C",
 ",,,,,,A,,,,,,,C,,,", 
 "", ",,,,,,,,,,Z,,,,,,,,")), .Names = c("Id", "Comments"),
class =    "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I tried your code, gsub didnt work but ifelse worked, I updated my question with a subset of my actual data using dput function

Comment: though output console shows `#[1] ""            "A,B,C,D,E,F" "A,D,S,D" ` when I open the dataframe t9  ` view(t9) ` still the same, none changed

Comment: @KimJenkins You have to assign the output to the column. i.e. `t9$Comments <- gsub(',+', ',', gsub('^,+|,+$', '', t9$Comments))`

Comment: lst time I tried this it didnt work and then I changed my logic to see if it makes things easier, so I have changed my dataset slightly.